# How to get all the Network connections going through the computer (linux) using python

Tags: python, networking, psutil

Okay, I already know that this question is going to attract a lot of down votes  however I am desperate for an answer. I am trying to get all the Network connections "calling home", with their IP's and hopefully the name of the program initiated the connection, on my Linux machine. I went through `psutils` documentation but I didn't find anything that'll will help. I went ahead to start reading `Sockets` documentation and for as far as I could understand what was going on. I didn't find the solution.

**IN SHORT** 
I am trying to get a list of all the programs that are connected to the internet on my system, kind of like a firewall does, but I am curious how would you do it with python, without obviously using the os.system().

Comment: Your question is rather unclear. A host will send all traffic destined for a different network to its configured gateway, so you could modify the host gateway configurations to point to the one computer. If the traffic is destined for the same network, then there is not much you can do because traffic is delivered directly from host-to-host on the LAN. That would require something like permanent ARP table entries for every possible host on the LAN to point to the MAC address of the computer.

Comment: I am trying to get a list of all the programs that are connected to the internet on my system, kind of like a firewall does, but I am curious how would you do it with python, without obviously using the `os.system()`. @RonMaupin

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example about how to get all network connections in "out" variable for Python:

```
import subprocess

proc = subprocess.Popen(["lsof -i"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
out, err = proc.communicate()
print ("network connections output:")
print (out)
```

After that you need to process the results and extract what you want.
Also please read more about lsof [here](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/08/lsof-command-examples/)